# For how long are the flagging rights disabled for a user?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, flag-ban

It was a mistake on my part due to my negligence of the rules. I chose **other (needs ♦ moderator attention)** as flags on 3 consecutive occasions because I wasn't sure of the type of flag to use in cases where the questions were too localized (missing an apostrophe, simple syntax error, not using quotes etc).

I didn't find anything suitable that fit the description of *too localized* under **it should be closed for another reason...** and hence decided to go for **other**. As it turns out, I can't flag questions now and was wondering for how long will this be in effect?

Right now whenever I try to flag, I'm getting *Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!* When I click on the *review* link in that message I'm directed to a page which shows my last 3 flags having a comment which says ***declined - Please use standard close votes or close flags for this instead of flagging for moderators.***

What is confusing here is what did the message mean when it said *please review them....* in this context? Because going to the review page isn't giving me an option to do something. All I can see there is the question, my flag, and the comment stating the reason for the decline.

Comment: "Depending on when and how those declined flags were cast, this block could last for as little as a day, and won't ever be longer than a week." -- find more details at MSE: [Allow recovery from flag hellban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/165773)

Comment: Well, the 3 flags were raised within 24 hours of each other. So I guess it was considered as abuse of the system. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Well, it's been a week now and the ban is still active. Not sure what my options are now

Comment: given the date of your post, week (7 days) has not yet expired as of today

Comment: I made this post a day after getting the ban....

Comment: well, I would probably wait for a day more, to make 200% sure that 7 [consecutive days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/consecutive-days/info) are expired indeed, then, if ban isn't over yet by then, flag [this very meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253700/839601) for mod attention, asking them to take a look

Comment: Yeh well, I guess that's the best way to go about it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Allright! The ban has been lifted :)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question.